# Clear empty value from List - Robot framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am a list which is - ['','','','Some-Value','',''] , I am trying to remove all the null/empty values from list so that the final result be ['Some-Value'].

Below is the code which I tried but so no luck so far

```
${list_size} = Get Length ${list}

For ${index} IN RANGE ${list_size}
     ${item} Get Form List ${list} ${index}
     Run Keyword if '${item}' == '' Remove ${item} from list ${list}
    enter code here
End
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem ? Thank you!

Comment: Iterate the loop and look for ascii value between {65-90} and {97-122}, remove everything which is not in that bracket

Comment: Never modify a list you are iterating over - you will change it, while the loop doesn't know that, and will eventually throw index out of bound exception. You could create a new list variable, and append to it all elements that match your condition.

Comment: Is this your actual code? You don't have enough spaces after `Run Keyword if` and `Remove ${item} from ${list}`. You should be getting a syntax error. Please provide a _working_ [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Robot framework enables you to use [Evaluate](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword, and than it is just a python problem.
This code example produces the result you are looking for.

```
*** Variables ***

@{list_variable}    ${empty}    some text    ${empty}

*** Test Cases ***
Replace a String
    ${cleared_list}=    Evaluate    [x for x in @{list_variable} if x]
    Log    ${cleared_list}
```

Comment: Just change `@{list_variable}` inside the list comprehension with `@list_variable`; the first will make RF substitute it with the string representation of the list - which can easily break, while the second will make the framework pass the variable directly to python.

Comment: Hello, thank you.. i Got the idea and was able to get the solution... What is used 

${cleared_list}=    Evaluate    [x for x in ${List} if x]

Comment: thank you for your use of ${empty} - it served the purpose of removing blank href entries in a list of href values scraped from a page: ${final_list_minus_junk_href}=  remove values from list     ${element_attribute_list}   ${empty}